# How to restrict slashes from encrypted text

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography

I am encrypting text using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in C#

Following is my code

```
  private static string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

I want to restrict '/' and '\' from appearing in the encrypted text. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it should work.

```
var encryptedText = Encrypt("MY SECRET MESSAGE");
var encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedText).Replace('/', '*');

var decodedText = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText.Replace('*', '/'));
var descriptedText = Decrypt(decodedText);
```

[`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) converts the input string to base64 characters only:

> The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero are the uppercase characters "A" to "Z", the lowercase characters "a" to "z", the numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/". The valueless character, "=", is used for trailing padding.

The obvious issue is the forward slash, so you can replace it with whatever character you want that's not also used in the base64 encoding. Just remember to convert back when you need to decrypt.

As [owlstead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259) points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310128/#comment39455081_25311024) it may be best to conform to some type of standard. [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7) defines a base64 encoding that meets your needs by substituting `+` with `-` and `/` by `_`. I didn't immediately see a way to do this built into .NET, so I'll provide some sample methods:

```
public static string ToBase64UrlString(string text)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(text)
        .Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
}

public static string FromBase64UrlString(string text)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(
        text.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/'))
}
```

Comment: It is probably a good idea to use the [base64url](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#page-7) encoding instead. It replaces `+` by `-` and `/` by `_`.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks, added more information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was replacing with '-', and problems started when the original string really had '-' symbol in it. Understanding the output of the ConvertToBase64 solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In case some Java dev (like me) wanders here: in my case I was using `java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("text")` to encode text and simply by changing it to `java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString("text")` (which uses `Encoder.RFC4648_URLSAFE`) it generated URL safe encodings.

Answer (score -1):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx)

> The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero are the uppercase characters "A" to "Z", the lowercase characters "a" to "z", the numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/". The valueless character, "=", is used for trailing padding.

There is no backslashes in *base64* normally.

To deal with slashes you have to either use different way of presenting byte array (your own) or simply decode `/` into something afterwards.

To example,

```
var text = Encrypt(...);
var textWithoutSlashes = text.Replace(@"\", "THISISSLASHOMG");
```

Similarly you will have to *restore* slashes before calling `Decrypt()` to restore `clearText`.